# Basic graphing - plot v = 10i +4

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

So I have the function $v=10i+4$ where $v$ is the horizontal axis and $i$ is the vertical axis. Please excuse me for such a basic question but I can't work out how to draw this function.

I figure if $v=something +4$ then I know the line intersects the $v$ axis at 4. This won't change the slope of the line, just the starting point.

So I have my starting point at v=4, i=0. I figure $1v=10i$ so I make a mark at $1$ on the $v$ axis and $10$ on the $i$ axis then draw a line from that point to the starting point on the $v$ axis.

However this doesn't seem to be right and I can't work out why. Can someone please explain where I have gone wrong in drawing this graph.

Comment: You're probably getting confused by a use of different variable names. You are probably familiar with $x$ and $y$ ? Just replace $v$ with $x$ and $i$ with $y$ to get $x=10y+4$, or rearranging $y=(x-4)/10=x/10-2/5.$ Since this is the equation of a line, let $x=0$ to get a $y$ value, then let $y=0$ to get an $x$ value. Plot these two coordinates and join them to get your line.

Comment: Okay thank you. I should have known to just set my values to equal zero. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$v=10i+4$ , replace $v$ by $x$ and $i$ by $y$ $\therefore x=10y+4$

$10y=x-4 \Rightarrow y=\frac{x}{10}-\frac{4}{10}$

This is the equation of a straight line with slope=$1/10$ and y-intercept=$-4/10=-2/5$ and x-intercept=$4$

can you draw a line passing through $(0,\large\frac{-2}{5})$ and $(4,0,)$